# My internet is not working properly

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, mobile-hotspot

I use wifi on my Windows 10 using my mobile hotspot. Recently, the connection stopped working properly. Some of the sites like - Facebook, Youtube, ilovepdf.com, support.hp.com are working. Other sites like coursera.org, amazon.in, pinterest.com  and many others are not working. It says, their server IP could not be found. My mobile internet works on the laptop when tethered using the USB cable.

My proxy settings are set at automatic. I also ran the Windows Network Diagnosis. I have updated some Wireless LAN drivers also. I tried using other mobile phones also. I am still not able to access other websites.

Please help me find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try using another dns service. There is a public dns service by google.
See [tutorial] how to change dns settings in winwods 10[1](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-dns-servers-in-windows-2626242).

Set the ips to

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

as shown on the screenshot. Those are google dns ips.

Answer (score 0):

For your phone, turn Airplane Mode ON, wait 30 seconds, turn Airplane mode OFF. Shut the phone down and wait a bit.

For the computer, run TCP/IP Reset
Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer

Now while the computer is restarting, start up the phone. Let everything get fully started and try the connection agan